# Wrong column span with multicolumn

Tags: formatting, multicolumn

I have a four columns `array` or `tabular`.  In the first row the second cell should span two columns, while in the second row both the first and the second cells should span two columns.  The result is not the expected one (see the example).  Moreover, using `tabular` the alignment of vertical lines is faulty.  Adding a first or last "regular" row (the one with numbers) solves the problem, but of course I do not want additional rows.  Why is this happening?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
         & Wrong & Correct
         \\
         Array & $
         \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|} \hline
              a & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{b} & c \\ \hline
              \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{d} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{e} \\ \hline
         \end{array}
         $ & $
         \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|} \hline
              1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ \hline
              a & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{b} & c \\ \hline
              \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{d} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{e} \\ \hline
         \end{array}
         $ \\ \hline
         Tabular & 
         \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|} \hline
              a & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{b} & c \\ \hline
              \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{d} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{e} \\ \hline
         \end{tabular}
         &
         \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|} \hline
              a & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{b} & c \\ \hline
              \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{d} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{e} \\ \hline
              1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ \hline
         \end{tabular}
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm unsure why you're expecting something different: just compute (by eyesight) the widths of the columns and you'll understand what's happening.

Comment: @egreg:  Mmmm.  Do you mean that the second "natural" column has neglillible or null width?  I thought the column was just missing.

Comment: Exactly so; that column does not even exist when TeX typesets the table, because it's always spanned with other columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the expected result, I'm afraid: when typesetting a table, a column whose cells are always merged with others is effectively removed. You need fixed width columns and also to remove intercolumn space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begingroup\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{|C{2em}|C{2em}|C{2em}|C{2em}|} \hline
a & \multicolumn{2}{C{4em}|}{b} & c \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|C{4em}|}{d} & \multicolumn{2}{C{4em}|}{e} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]